# How to extract strings from /etc/oratab file?

Tags: python, list, extract

I‘m trying to separate the database names form a file called /etc/oratab:

```
#Commends
DBNAME1:/opt/oracle/product/19000/db:N
DBNAME2:/opt/oracle/product/19000/db:N
```

The following code returns only DBNAME1:

```
def oratab():
    dblist=[]
    flag=False
    with open('/etc/oratab', 'r') as oratab:
        for line in oratab:
           if line and line[0].isalpha():
              flag=True
           if flag:
              dblist.append(line)
    return ''.join(dblist).split(':')[0]
```

How to change the script to get the full list of DBNames?

Comment: you must have to debug it first and find if the db name list is in the 'oratab'

Comment: I'm just curious on the purpose of the flag=True & if flag: section of code :-) It could induce a bug of considering all lines after the first proper line right?

Comment: Can I recommend you adding a `not flag` condition to the first if to shortcut once you already have set the flag? `if not flag and line and line[0].isalpha():`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `dblist` is list of `lines` and you want to return the first element from `split` line not `dblist`.

```py
','.join(dbline.split(':')[0] for bdline in dblist)
```

I think you need to return the `list` of `database names` in list if so
remove the `join` and just return `return dblist`

Better:

```
def oratab():
    dblist=[]
    with open('/etc/oratab', 'r') as oratab:
        for line in oratab:
           if line and line[0].isalpha():
              dblist.append(line.split(':')[0])
    return ','.join(dblist)
```

Or shorter

```py
def oratab():
    dblist = []
    with open('/etc/oratab', 'r') as oratab:
        dblist = [line.split(':')[0] in oratab if line and line[0].isalpha()]
    return ','.join(dblist)
```

Comment: I know in the question he does the `''.join()` part but I think he does not need that, I think it was part of his try to get all the DBs.

Comment: Yes you are right or just remove continue and perform append thanks

Comment: (You're missing the quotes on `":"` in your first code snippet.) I know there are sometimes these glitches when first answering :^)